# ui grid load only update row from database to table

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am able to update the row using ui-grid by calling web service. I want that to be refresh that row form database. Please tell me.. 
To display that right now i am updating the entire row.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can call this code:

```
$scope.gridApi.core.refresh();
```

hope it works